# Using QGIS Relations with the Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have set up relations for my QGIS project (version 2.8.3 on windows 7 64 bit). I can see the related features when identifying the map.

I'm now trying to get this information onto a print composer.

My first idea was to get the information into the attribute table item--but I have not successfully gotten the related entities in the parent attribute table nor the attribute table item.

Does anyone have any suggestions on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Relations in QGIS are typically used for One-to-Many 1-M relations and as such the related attributes won't show in the parent's attribute table. This will break the one row per feature rule. You can use joins for 1-1 relations and in this case the related attributes will show in the parent's attribute table with a prefix.